# determine last row with php dynamic data

Tags: php

I am generating a dynamic list with php which looks like picture. It has 4 columns(fixed); but rows can vary.

```
GREEN = first column
RED = last row
```

How can I get the GREEN and RED ones (for css purpose)?

```
echo '<ul>'
foreach($data as $v){
   echo '<li>$v</li>'
}
echo '</ul>'
```

[image]

Explained:
each block is a li. the markup comes out like this:

```
<div class="content">
  <ul>
    <li>some data</li>
    <li>some data</li>
    <li>some data</li>
    <li>some data</li>
    <li>some data</li>
    <li>some data</li>
    <li>some data</li>
    <li>some data</li>
    <li>some data</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.content{ border-top:solid #000 1px, border-bottom:solid #000 1px}
ul{ border-left:solid #000 1px}
li{border-bottom:solid #000 1px; border-left:solid #000 1px}
```

- The 1st column (1st, 5th and 9th li) will not have border-left.
- The last row (8th and 9th li) will not have border-bottom

all i want is the whole thing looks like a table with cells. i cannot use table here, so i am trying to use list which looks like table. the lists are generating dynamically. so items can vary. I hope I am clear now.

Comment: its better to post full HTML why people imagine what is the code exactly

Comment: If Green is the first column, what's in the next 3?

Comment: Kindly rephrase your question and include some example of the array structure using code.

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear. Do you want all elements in the last row to be red or only in the last container? Why are there two elements with different colors in the next to last row? Do you want to add a class with PHP to the specific elements or do you want to create CSS selectors to target the specific elements?

Comment: The question is explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

**CSS**

```
div.content {
    width: 403px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
    width: 403px;
    margin: 0 0 -1px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
}

li:nth-child(4n+4) {
    border-right: 0;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/AWy6H/)

Comment: This helps. but I am still curious about the php solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Imrul.H Can you explain, what you mean? You don't have to change your PHP code at all with this CSS code.

Comment: I want to say that, your solution works. But I wanted a PHP logic about this; rather than CSS solution.

Comment: But your PHP logic is exactly what you need for this, as simple as possible. Or do you want to work with classes, so that the last and next to last element get a CSS class that is added by your PHP script?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But anyways, I am using your CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use CSS to do this instead of PHP. Take a look at [CSS nth-child pseudo-element](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).